# The proof of $\frac{\partial g_j}{\partial x_i} g_i = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \Big(\frac{1}{2} |\vec{g}|^2 \delta_{ij} \Big) $.

Tags: summation, vectors, tensors

I want to prove that

$$\frac{\partial g_j}{\partial x_i} g_i = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \Big(\frac{1}{2} |\vec{g}|^2 \delta_{ij} \Big) $$
where $g_i$ is from the gravitational force $F_i = m g_i$.

Could you tell me how the **Kronecker-Delta symbol** come into this equation?

Comment: It would help if you defined your terms.  What is $g$?  What is $\vec g$?  What are the $g_j$?  Thanks.

Comment: Is $g_{i}$ function of one variable $x_{i}$ or variables $x_{1}, \dots, x_{n}$?

Comment: @See-WooLee Actually, this problem is from physics. $g_i$ is the gravitational acceleration vector, and $x_i$ means its direction. So I think $g_i$ could be treated as a function of variable $x_i$ and $x_j$.

Comment: @RobertLewis Thanks for the suggestion! I've defined $g$ term now.